# association between user and 2 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't seem to solve this problem.

I have a **user** model. The user can create a **tour**. The users can also book other people's tours, by sending a **tour_request**.

Currently my associations are these:

**user.rb**

```
has_many :tours
has_many :tour_requests
```

**tour.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :tour_requests
```

**tour_request.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :tour
```

I would like for a user to be able to view when a user has requested a tour_request for a tour they created.

I tried:

```
current_user.tours.tour_requests.all
```

but that leaves me with undefined method for tour_requests.

Anybody know how I can configure the relationships so that I'm able to get that working?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am missing something but, why are you trying to get to the `tour_requests` via `tours`? You have the association on your `user` object:

```
current_user.tour_requests.each do |tour_request| ... end
```

Also, bear in mind that `current_user.tours` is an ActiveRecord result set (i.e., it holds all the ActiveRecord tour objects). So, that call will never work.

At the least, you'd have to do something along the lines of the code below. Granted there are lots of ways to go about this but, ultimately, if you want to get the `tour_requests` from the `tour` object, it must be off a single instance of a `tour` and not a collection.

```
current_user.tours.each do |tour|
  tour.tour_requests
end
```

Comment: If you have created a tour. I would like to display who have requested a booking of a tour you have created.

So if i create a tour with id #2, and you as another user create a tour request for that tour (id #2) I'd like it to say that craig has requested a tour for id #2.

Comment: I think I understand what you're after ... then it seems as though you'd want to do it more like my second code block, where you iterate over the tour_requests that are associated with each tour. You could then do any conditional checks inside that block to see if a user requested the tour, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over tours to get requests, like Craig has mentioned, or you can create another association like

```
class User
  # ...
  has_many users_tour_requests, through: :tours, source: :tour_requests
end

# then you have something like 
user.users_tour_requests
```

Obviously you need to have a separate name for this new association, as you already have existing association with `tour_requests` name. Because of that You need to specify a source which should be picked up inside `tours` association.

With [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association), when you only need to fetch your tours tour requests it will generate a proper query to get those, instead of firstly getting tours, and then tour_requests.